# Illegal collation when running query with UNION

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

When I run a UNION statement the values returned in one column are either utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode ci. The other column in the UNION is NULL.

When the data in the first sub-query is utf8_general_ci the results return however if the data is in utf8_unicode_ci collation, I get the illegal collation error.

Can someone shed light on why the only utf8_unicode_ci presents the problem?

Comment: Generally the types (possibly including the collations) of all data in each column of a union needs to be the same.  To fix this, stop mixing collations.

Comment: Specifics, please.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the SQL, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';